# Using Parallel Test annotation for Apex mocking framework

Tags: apex, unit-test, apexmock

Currently in my org there are around 50 test class which just uses Apex mocking framework and has no interaction with database. I have other test classes that is actual Apex test classes(around 1000+). I know tests written using Apex mocks runs quicker since there is no database interaction.

Would adding @isTest(Parallel=True) would make Apex mock test classes more faster? I know using it on test classes that interacts with database can make it faster but the concern is those classes share the same data and can result in failure(UNABLE TO LOCK ROW ERROR). Hence I am exploring this idea only for test that are based on Apex mocks framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this approach.

First, using this default execution options as below, run all the test classes.

[image: Apex test execution option]

If you found any failure in the test class due to this parallel running, then select  `Disable Parallel Apex Testing` checkbox.

Then those test classes which don't have clashing, for those use `@isTest(Parallel=True)`, since this overrides the default behavior of Apex test Execution Options.

> Use the @isTest(isParallel=true) annotation to indicate test classes that can run in parallel and aren’t restricted by the default limits on the number of concurrent tests. This makes the execution of test classes more efficient, because more tests can be run in parallel.
>
> This annotation overrides the default settings that disable parallel testing. A test class that doesn’t have this annotation is restricted by the default limits on the number of concurrent tests.

Comment: So basically I would need to identify test classes that wont fail if I use Parallel=True? Any thoughts on using it for Apex Mock test classes( I see they are efficient themselves, so not sure if it would make considerable difference)

Comment: exactly, first do run all test classes to get if failure occurs

Comment: difference will be there if text classes run serially, it will take time for deployment

Comment: Do i need to check - Disable parallel apex testing , when I have IsParallel= true in some test classes. I believe irrespective of that , it will run in parallel for classes with which has Isparalled=true annotation. Is that correct?

Comment: If no test class fails then dont select the checkbox and no need to put isparallel=true. Because test classes execute parallely always.

Comment: I am using ant migration tool and noticing that for some reason all test are running serially by default. I see in Ant migration guide pdf , it says -  Apex tests that run as part of a deployment always run synchronously and serially. https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

Comment: Then use isParallel=true as to serve your purpose

Comment: I have IsParallel=True but still using ant migration it runs serially.